# Which `[InternalsVisibleTo]` for .NET Framework and .NET Standard / Core framework assemblies?

Tags: .net, .net-core, castle-dynamicproxy, base-class-library, internalsvisibleto

I'm having an issue with cross-assembly / friend assembly type visibility.

I have the following program (which I sign / strong-name). It tells Castle DynamicProxy (I'm using version 4.2.1 of the `Castle.Core` NuGet package) to create a proxy for my interface `IFoo`. I'm also specifying that my `internal class InterfaceProxyBase` should be the base class for the proxy type.

DynamicProxy then uses `System.Reflection.Emit` to create the proxy type. But apparently, `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder` does not have access to `InterfaceProxyBase`.

```cs
// [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("?")]
//                               ^^^
// What do I need here for my program to work both on the .NET Framework 4.5+
// and on .NET Core / .NET Standard 1.3+?

using Castle.DynamicProxy;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();

        var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions
            {
                BaseTypeForInterfaceProxy = typeof(InterfaceProxyBase)  // <--
            };

        var proxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(
                typeof(IFoo),
                options,
                new Interceptor());
    }
}

public interface IFoo { }

internal abstract class InterfaceProxyBase { }

internal sealed class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) { }
}
```

---

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied: 'InterfaceProxyBase'.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   ...
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Program.Main() in Program.cs
```

So, apparently I need an `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute for the framework's own assembly / assemblies. My program (a class library, actually) targets both .NET 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.3.

Which `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute(s) do I need (including the precise public keys) to make my code work for the mentioned platforms / targets?

---

P.S.: I know that I can circumvent the problem by just making `InterfaceProxyBase` public and hiding it with `[EditorBrowsable(Never)]` for appearance's sake, but I really don't want to make this internal type public if I don't have to.

P.P.S.: If making internals public to framework assemblies is a really bad idea, security-wise, please let me know, then I'll happily reconsider my approach.

Comment: Cannot you try "Castle.Core"? What's the result?

Comment: @LexLi: That's what I tried first. Making internals visible to Castle.Core doesn't have any noticeable effect. Then I took a look at the stack trace and saw that the exception is triggered by `TypeBuilder` inside the framework; not by Castle. I would've expected permissions to bubble down from Castle into the framework (those pesky `LinkDemand` thingies I never really understood), but apparently that's not how it works these days.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set to `mscorlib` for .NET Framework, and `System.Reflection.Emit` for .NET Core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=netframework-4.7.1 But I wonder if Castle offers you a better way. Can you try to check how `TypeBuilder` is used in Castle (from the exception call stack)? That might give you some hints.

Comment: @LexLi: That might be worth a shot. I've obviously already tried `mscorlib`, `System`, `System.Core`, and `System.Reflection.Emit` (on .NET Core), the difficulty is knowing which public key(s) to include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set `InternalsVisibleTo` for `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

`DynamicProxyGenAssembly2` is a temporary assembly built by `Castle.DynamicProxy`. This assembly contains generated proxy type that inherits from your `InterfaceProxyBase`. That's why `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2` should have an access to `InterfaceProxyBase` type. The possible options are either adding `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute or making `InterfaceProxyBase` public.

Comment: Ah... of course! I was under the false impression that it was the framework assemblies failing to access `InterfaceProxyBase`, when the "access denied" is really triggered by the inheritance relationship between the interface proxy type generated in `DynamicProxyGenAssembly2` and `InterfaceProxyBase`. Could you please add this as a short explanation to your answer, then I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have added this note to my answer.